# Android notifications - Is it possible to display Toast/Alert/etc. at home screen?

Tags: android, notifications, homescreen

Is it possible to display any type of notification (from my application) on home screen?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Think we need more information, because yes this is possible but you must mean something specific as you've asked the question?

Comment: I would like to create mobile notifier application. E.g. when e-mail arrives message is push to home screen. This picture shows exactly what I want: [notification](http://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/android/devguide/images/custom_toast.png). Is it possible to do it?

Comment: Ah..  I understand now.. that is not something I have done before so I don't know. (it is something I would like to do though with sms so would love to see how you do it!) 
Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4025082/android-toast-started-from-service-only-displays-once I assume it's from a service?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make a **background service** for your application, which **receives any notification (For new SMS or EMAIL) from Broadcast Receiver** and when it receives event, just display a `Toast` from your service.