# Android app crashes on boot

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am new to Eclipse and Java development and I am trying to start an activity on boot. I've read multiple threads discussing this topic and while I have managed to start the application on boot, it crashes.

This is my code:

AndroidManifest.xml :

```
<!--
Below the <manifest> opening tag:
-->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
<!--
Inside the <application> tag:
-->
<receiver android:name="com.example.Autostart">  
        <intent-filter>  
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />  
        </intent-filter>  
</receiver>

<service android:name="com.example.service" android:enabled="true" />
```

Autostart.java :

```
package com.example;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;

public class Autostart extends BroadcastReceiver{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) 
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(arg0, service.class);
        arg0.startService(intent);
    }
}
```

service.java :

```
package com.example;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class service extends Service{

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startid)
    {
        Intent intents = new Intent(getBaseContext(),checker.class);
        intents.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(intents);
        Toast.makeText(this, "My Service Started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

}
```

My checker class has an OnCreate function which alters some settings values.

The only thing that I see when I start my phone is that "YourAppName has stopped working", which means that the application has crashed. I do not see any Toast message.

When I normally open my application and I read the settings that ought to be written on startup, nothing is there.

Comment: Can you share your logscat .. ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Error calling toast from Service Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12498226/error-calling-toast-from-service-android)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I hadn't declared my activity to the manifest file.

Answer (score 0):

Change like this in your manifest and try it:

```
  <receiver android:enabled="true" android:name=".Autostart"
    android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED">

    <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```