# null pointer exception with Handler in new thread started in Service, Android

Tags: android, service, handler, android-context

I'm not able to print out a simple Toast message from my android Service class:

```
 @Override
public void run() {
    handler.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Toast.makeText(context, "thread is running", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }); 
  }
```

This run method is inside of a Service that is implementing the `Runnable` class, for that reason I am using `handler.post`, however cannot get anything to work inside of the inner `run()` method.   I thought that `handler.post` would post would work,  what is wrong?

the rest of the code and the logcat printout is below;

```
public class LotteryServer extends Service implements Runnable {

            Handler handler = new Handler();
            Context context = this;

            @Override
            public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId){
                 super.onStartCommand(intent, startId, startId);
                 Toast.makeText(context, "My Service Started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                 return START_STICKY;
            }

            @Override
            public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
                 // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                 return null;
            }
            @Override   
            public void onDestroy() {
                super.onDestroy();
                Toast.makeText(context, "My Service Stopped", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            @Override
            public void run() {
            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                     @Override
                     public void run() {
                          Toast.makeText(context, "thread is running",     Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                     }
            }); 

    }
}
```

LogCat;

```
02-21 15:09:33.279: E/AndroidRuntime(24038): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-21 15:09:33.279: E/AndroidRuntime(24038): java.lang.NullPointerException
02-21 15:09:33.279: E/AndroidRuntime(24038): at android.content.ContextWrapper.getResources(ContextWrapper.java:81)
02-21 15:09:33.279: E/AndroidRuntime(24038):    at android.widget.Toast.<init>(Toast.java:92)
02-21 15:09:33.279: E/AndroidRuntime(24038):    at android.widget.Toast.makeText(Toast.java:233)
02-21 15:09:33.279: E/AndroidRuntime(24038):    at com.lottery.clientplayer.LotteryServer$1.run(LotteryServer.java:44)
02-21 15:09:33.279: E/AndroidRuntime(24038):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
02-21 15:09:33.279: E/AndroidRuntime(24038):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
02-21 15:09:33.279: E/AndroidRuntime(24038):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-21 15:09:33.279: E/AndroidRuntime(24038):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4699)
02-21 15:09:33.279: E/AndroidRuntime(24038):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-21 15:09:33.279: E/AndroidRuntime(24038):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-21 15:09:33.279: E/AndroidRuntime(24038):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:790)
02-21 15:09:33.279: E/AndroidRuntime(24038):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:557)
02-21 15:09:33.279: E/AndroidRuntime(24038):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: It seems your context in the makeText() is null.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4026240/1339473 k bro @system32

Comment: @altaf He's using a `Service` not `Activity`

Answer (score 1):

Change this

```
Toast.makeText(context, "thread is running", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

to

```
Toast.makeText(LotteryServer.this, "thread is running", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Toast.makeText(context, "thread is running", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

instead  context use getApplicationContxt() hope this can work.. because tht will get a scop of whole Context. try it

Comment: tried that but,  getApplicationContext() is also resulting in null pointer

Answer (score 0):

Use runOnUIThread(Runnable)
if that doesnot work, try this

```
Handler mHandler = new Handler();
final Runnable mUpdateResults = new Runnable() {
public void run() {
    Toast(this, message, duration).show();
}

new Thread() {
 public void run() {
    mHandler.post(mUpdateResults);
 }
}.start();
```

Comment: runOnUiThread does not work in a service, it is giving compile error,  about the code you posed, tried it and it will crash if I put the Toast inside the run method()

Comment: Handler mHandler = new Handler();
 final Runnable mUpdateResults = new Runnable() {
 public void run() {
    // Toast.makeText(context, "My Service Stopped", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
 }
 };
 
 @Override
 public void run() {
  mHandler.post(mUpdateResults);
  
  
  
 } // end run method